# Build git from source with system git config at /etc/gitconfig

Tags: git, shell, ubuntu

I use:

```sh
    version=2.35.1
    installDir=/usr/local
    url="https://github.com/git/git/archive/refs/tags/v$gitVersion.tar.gz"

    tempDir=$(mktemp -d) &&
        mkdir -p "$tempDir" &&
        (
            cd "$tempDir" &&
                curl -L "$url" -o git.tar.gz &&
                tar -xf git.tar.gz &&
                cd "$tempDir/git-"* &&
                make configure &&
                ./configure --prefix="$installDir" \
                    --with-curl \
                    --with-expat \
                    --with-openssl \
                    --without-python \
                    --without-tcltk &&
                make -j all &&
                sudo make -j install
```

to install Git
but when I use `git config --sytstem` it looks into `/usr/local/etc/gitconfig`
which is not what I was expecting.

How can I make a build which uses /etc/gitconfig as the system config?

Comment: Most `configure`-based software has a `--sysconfdir` option that will probably help out here (e.g., `--sysconfdir=/etc`).

Comment: I found the solution `--with-gitconfig=/etc/gitconfig `